# Como passar dados entre componentes no React

Tags: javascript, react, contexto

> Bom, estou com a seguinte dúvida: Queria passar as informações de um componente para outro quando eu clicar no componente, tipo assim:

> Eu criei um contexto usando o ContextApi do React que provem as informações para todos os componentes da aplicação.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([
    {
      chatId: 1,
      title: "Fulano de Tal",
      image:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/01/21/11/avatar-1789663_960_720.png",
      numberPhone: "559198765432",
      status: "Online",
    },
  ]);
```

> Abaixo segue o componente chatList no qual eu quero clicar e passar as informações para o componente Header:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UsersContext } from "../../provider/context";
import "./styles.css";

export default function ChatList({ onClick, active, data }) {
  const date = new Date();
  let hours = date.getHours();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  const { user } = useContext(UsersContext);

  return (
    <div className={`chatlistItem ${active ? "active" : ""}`} onClick={onClick}>
      <img src={user[0].image} className="chatlistItem-avatar" />
      <div className="chatlistItem-lines">
        <div className="chatlistItem-line">
          <div className="chatlistItem-name">{user[0].title}</div>
          <div className="chatlistItem-date">
            {hours}:{minutes}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="chatlistItem-line">
          <div className="chatlistItem-lastMsg">
            <p>{user[0].status}</p>
            {/* <p></p> */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Aqui está o componente em que quero receber as informações vindas do chatList:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import MoreVertIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";
import ChatIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Chat";
import { UsersContext } from "../../provider/context";

export default function Header() {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UsersContext);
  const { handleChatInternal } = useContext(UsersContext);

  return (
    <div className="chat-header">
      <div className="chat-header-info">
        <img src={user[0].image} className="chat-avatar" />
        <div className="containerInfo">
          <div className="chat-name">{user[0].title}</div>
          <p className="chat-status">{user[0].status}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="chatWindow-headerbuttons" title="Pesquisar conversa">
        <div className="chat-btn">
          <SearchIcon style={{ color: "#999" }} />
        </div>

        <div className="chat-btn" title="Opções">
          <MoreVertIcon style={{ color: "#999" }} />
        </div>

        <div
          className="chat-btn"
          title="Chat interno"
          onClick={handleChatInternal}
        >
          <ChatIcon style={{ color: "#999" }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Caso tenham alguma dúvida, ou se algo não ficou muito claro, por favor mandem aqui pra eu saber.

Answer (score -2):

Lucas, para isso que vc precisa, acredito que o melhor seria usar uma função de callback, vc cria uma prop que vai receber a função que sera executada, mas esta função está especificada no pai, na documentação do react tem um exemplo: [Passando Funções para Componentes](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html).

O context api do react foi idealizado para outra finalidade, que é passar informações de um componente avô para um componente neto, sem ter que passar pelo pai: [Context](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).